# Parallax Effect for HTML Elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, parallax, parallax.js

I am looking for a `parallax effec`t that I can apply to a **HTML ELEMENT**. I have gone through so many libraries available on internet, and all of the parallax effects are applied to a element that containing a background image.

But here what I want is, instead of having a `fixed` element and scroll, I want the entire element to be scrolled in the page.

As you can see in the following example I don't want to keep a `background-image`, I need to keep a `img` and add `parallax` effect to the `img element`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //.parallax(xPosition, speedFactor, outerHeight) options:
  //xPosition - Horizontal position of the element
  //inertia - speed to move relative to vertical scroll. Example: 0.1 is one tenth the speed of scrolling, 2 is twice the speed of scrolling
  //outerHeight (true/false) - Whether or not jQuery should use it's outerHeight option to determine when a section is in the viewport
  $('.bg').parallax("50%", 0.5);

})
```

```css
#second .bg {
  background: url(https://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/images/trainers.png) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  height: 200vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/scripts/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/scripts/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/scripts/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>


<div id="second">
  <div class="story">
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
      <h2>Multiple Backgrounds</h2>
      <p>The multiple backgrounds applied to this section are moved in a similar way to the first section -- every time the user scrolls down the page by a pixel, the positions of the backgrounds are changed.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio.
        Donec egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien.
        Sed pulvinar.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio.
        Donec egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien.
        Sed pulvinar.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio.
        Donec egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien.
        Sed pulvinar.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio.
        Donec egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien.
        Sed pulvinar.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio.
        Donec egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien.
        Sed pulvinar.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio.
        Donec egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien.
        Sed pulvinar.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--.story-->

</div>
<!--#second-->
```

Comment: I Guess this is what you are looking for... 
https://codepen.io/ungmo2/pen/NRpZzd 
https://codepen.io/moseke/pen/zNVZOx

Comment: Exactly this fills my requirement sir. Thank you. @George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the reference on the accepted answer I created my own snippet which works as I required.

Reference : https://codepen.io/ungmo2/pen/NRpZzd

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    parallaxScroll();
  });

  function parallaxScroll() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#parallax-bg-3').css('top', (0 - (scrolled * .25)) + 'px');
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgba(230, 231, 232, 1);
}


/* background layer */

div#parallax-bg-3 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}


/* foreground */

div#parallax-bg-3 div {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#bg-3-1 {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS27TYuN4qwAy48c_n-dVKgnIOwwyg7JcHbZJ1CRi8CQkWoYzKJ');
  width: 250px;
  height: 210px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: red;
}

div#bg-3-1 p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>The multiple backgrounds applied to this section are moved in a similar way to the first section -- every time the user scrolls down the page by a pixel, the positions of the backgrounds are changed.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio. Donec
  egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien. Sed pulvinar.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio. Donec
  egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien. Sed pulvinar.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio. Donec
  egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien. Sed pulvinar.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio. Donec
  egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien. Sed pulvinar.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio. Donec
  egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien. Sed pulvinar.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio. Donec
  egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien. Sed pulvinar.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio. Donec
  egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien. Sed pulvinar.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio. Donec
  egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien. Sed pulvinar.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio. Donec
  egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien. Sed pulvinar.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nibh erat, sagittis sit amet congue at, aliquam eu libero. Integer molestie, turpis vel ultrices facilisis, nisi mauris sollicitudin mauris, volutpat elementum enim urna eget odio. Donec
  egestas aliquet facilisis. Nunc eu nunc eget neque ornare fringilla. Nam vel sodales lectus. Nulla in pellentesque eros. Donec ultricies, enim vitae varius cursus, risus mauris iaculis neque, euismod sollicitudin metus erat vitae sapien. Sed pulvinar.</p>
<div id="parallax-bg-3" class="parallax-bg">
  <div id="bg-3-1">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```